# Underscore template: Reference Error template variable

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have two different pages, each with their own page specific JS script.

Both of these pages are calling the same generic function, using exactly the same data, but one works fine and the other throws a reference error for one of the template variables.

Global function:

```
createTunnelDropdown: function (element, data){
    var tpl = _.template('<option value="<%= id %>"><%= name %></option>');
    var sorted = _.sortBy(data, 'title');
    _.each(sorted, function(obj) {
        element.append(tpl({"id": obj.id, "name":  obj.title}));
    }); 
},
```

Working function call:

```
//create our dropdown tunnel list
var tunnels         = IBA.tunnels;
var select  = $("#member_tunnel"); 
IBA.app.createTunnelDropdown(select, tunnels);
```

Non working function call:

```
//create our dropdown tunnel list
var tunnels     = IBA.tunnels;
var select  = $("#tunnel"); 
IBA.app.createTunnelDropdown(select, tunnels);
```

Error Message:

```
VM3923:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not define VM3923:5c
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from that `element.append(tpl(...))` call? A ReferenceError from a compiled template generally means that you're not supplying values for everything the template uses but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Yes but I've realized there is one difference that may be affecting things. The first example builds a SELECT statement within the body of the main page, the second within a Bootstrap Modal window. Not sure how this would affect it but thought I'd add that.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem so that it can be reproduced. Shouldn't matter where `select` is since the error is coming from the `tpl(...)` call, right?

Comment: Exactly. So how do I isolate the problem? I've checked the data that the global function receives from the separate calls, it's exactly the same. But the issue doesn't appear to be with the data, it appears to be it can't find the template variable right?

Comment: Start by stepping through the code in a debugger. My first guess is that it isn't coming from where you think it is, given `t = _.template('<%= id %>')`, `t({id: anything_at_all})` won't raise a ReferenceError so I don't see how your `tpl` call would cause the error you're seeing.